# Video4Linux ioctl error (#25) when attempting to read device information from /dev/video0

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, video4linux

I am currently attempting to retrieve device information for a built in web-cam using the following code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/media.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   int fd = open("/dev/video0", O_RDONLY, 0);
   if (fd > 0) {
       struct media_device_info *device_data = (struct media_device_info *) malloc (sizeof(struct media_device_info) * 1);

       if (ioctl(fd, MEDIA_IOC_DEVICE_INFO, device_data) ==  0)
            printf("Media Version: %u\nDriver: %s\nVersion: %d\nSerial: %s\n", (unsigned int) device_data->media_version, device_data->driver, (int) device_data->driver_version, device_data->serial);
        else {
               fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't get device info: %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
       }

       close(fd);
       free(device_data);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When the code executes the else block is entered thus giving the following:

```
Couldn't get device info: 25: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

From this it would seem that the device is being opened in the wrong manner such that ioctl cannot use the file descriptor.  I must be missing something; could anyone here help me with regards to opening the /dev/video0 device?

Thanks!

p.s. If this has been answered before elsewhere please let me know.  If this question is invalid in anyway then please accept my apologies.

Comment: Do you have `/dev/media*`?

Comment: I don't know, but are you sure that you call correct open() function. In examples of ioctl() call open() takes only 2 arguments. But yourth function takes 3.

Comment: Also check if you compiled `linux` with `CONFIG_MEDIA_CONTROLLER` enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far,
(1) I do not have any /dev/media* devices
(2) I did try with the open method which takes 2 args, got the same result.
(3) Running `cat /boot/config-$(uname -r) | grep CONFIG_MEDIA_CONTROLLER` gives `CONFIG_MEDIA_CONTROLLER=y`

Comment: are you sure that kernel part supports this ioctl?

Comment: Good question @AlexHoppus, how would I check this?

Comment: is /dev/video0 correct device name? Have you chacked that your webcam works with other applications?

Comment: `v4l2-ctl -D -d /dev/video0` returns information about the device itself, the /dev/video0 device can be used by VLC etc.

Comment: According to http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/linux-doc-3.16/html/media_api/func-open.html the flags to `open` should be `O_RDWR`.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments, changing the flag to O_RDWR didn't do the trick.  I will continue to investigate and report back here.  Out of interest did the code work for anyone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `/dev/video*` devices may be bound to separate `/dev/media*` devices, and you need to issue your `MEDIA_IOC_DEVICE_INFO` ioctl against the corresponding `/dev/media*` device for your `/dev/video*` device.

As to how to locate that corresponding device id, the best I have come up with is to search for `media*` files within the `/sys/class/video4linux/video{N}/device` directory.

For example, for a given device `/dev/video0` on my system (kernel 4.15.0-34-generic), searching for `media*` files under `/sys/class/video4linux/video0/device` turned up `media10`, which I was then able to use to recover the serial number (open `/dev/media10`, issue the ioctl command).

I don't know whether this method of finding the corresponding media devices is consistent across distros/versions/kernels/etc.

Comment: Followed your steps and found that a media0 was now being listed, and behold it was indeed there- in the devices folder (/dev/media0).  So, good advice with regards to navigation.  Everybody else who commented were correct in their insistence that /dev/media0 should be present- why it wasn't listed before remains a mystery.